# Not quite sure why "count" is decreasing midway (java)

Tags: java, arrays, while-loop, count

As a homework, i was supposed to find the min number of steps needed to reach the last value in the array, assuming each step can only be a maximum of 50.

So, i did this :

```
import java.util.*;

class RabbitJumps {
  
  public static void main (String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter the number of rocks: ");
    int size = sc.nextInt();
    System.out.print("Enter locations of " +size+ " rocks: ");
    int[] rocks = new int[size];
    for (int i = 0; i<size; i++) {
      rocks[i] = sc.nextInt();
    }
    if (countJumps(rocks)==-1) {
      System.out.println("Impossible");
    } else {
      System.out.println(countJumps(rocks)+" jumps");
    }
  }
  public static int countJumps(int[] rocks) {
    for (int i = 0; i<rocks.length-1; i++) {
      if (rocks[i+1]-rocks[i]>50) {
        return -1;
      }
    }
    int count = 0;
    int distjumped = 0;
    while (distjumped < rocks[rocks.length-1]) {
      int whichrock = nextStep(rocks); 
      distjumped += rocks[whichrock];
      adjustArray(rocks, whichrock);
      count++;
      System.out.println("count = "+count);    //check
    }
    return count;
  }
  public static int nextStep(int[] rocks) {
    int dist = 0;
    int whichrock = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i<rocks.length; i++) {
      if (rocks[i]>dist && rocks[i]<=50) {
        dist=rocks[i];
        whichrock = i;
        System.out.println(dist);    // check
      } 
    }
    System.out.println("whichrock = "+whichrock);     //check
    return whichrock;
  }
  public static void adjustArray(int[] rocks, int whichrock) {
    int dist = rocks[whichrock];
    for (int i = 0; i<rocks.length; i++) {
      rocks[i]-=dist;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i<=whichrock; i++) {
      rocks[i]=0;
    }
  }
}
```

I'm not quite sure why the count's kinda wonky? like this: [image] I'm not sure why the count's starting from 1 again midway. This happens with other inputs as well :(
Would appreciate some help!! thanks guys!!

Comment: You call `countJumps` twice in `main()`. Once to test `if (countJumps(rocks)==-1)` and once in the `else` if that test fails at `System.out.println(countJumps(rocks)+" jumps");`

Comment: wait but how would that cause the "count" within the countJumps method to like revert to 1? for example, if i enter 11; 30 70 75 120 160 
170 180 190 200 246 258, it will run smoothly and count till 4 but it starts all over at 30 at the 5th round and count reverts to 1?  @JohnnyMopp

Comment: Because you modify the original list of `rocks` in `adjustArray()` so the 2nd time you call `countJumps()`, it's different data.

Comment: oHH that took quite awhile but i think i get it now... thanks!! @JohnnyMopp